# How to implement string-less-than filter on MongoDB UpdateOne in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to update a document in MongoDB, but only if the ETag on the updated item is newer than on the existing item. Currently, my request looks like this:

```
UpdateResult _ = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
    p => p.Guid.Equals(new Guid(id)) && string.Compare(p.ETag, etag) < 0,
    updater, new UpdateOptions(), token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, when I try this I'm getting a `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message of "Compare({document}{etag}, "637678355616597757") is not supported". I take this to mean that the `string.Compare` function is not valid in this context so I replaced it with `p.ETag.Equals(etag, StringComparison.Ordinal)` but that didn't work either.

*Update*
I switched the order of the conditions on the filter to `string.Compare(p.ETag, etag) < 0 && p.Guid.Equals(new Guid(id))` but the same error persists. This tells me that it's not an issue with the filter only accepting a single condition rather an issue with the string comparison, specifically.

With that in mind, how do I ensure that entries with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to implement the filter using an expression but this solution fixed the problems I was having:

```
FilterDefinition<TItem> filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<TItem>().And(
    new FilterDefinitionBuilder<TItem>().Eq(p => p.Guid, new Guid(id)),
    new FilterDefinitionBuilder<TItem>().Lt(p => p.ETag, etag));

UpdateResult _ = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, updater, 
    new UpdateOptions(), token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```